# VBA if statement does not trigger empty string VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

im trying to delete the content of an input field when the value of a related one is deleted.

However the if statement does not trigger when the value is Null ... (empty string)

I tested it with the "Hello" message box and it does not appear when the textbox is cleared, how it should.

```
Private Sub Student_AfterUpdate()


If Me.Student.Value = "" Then

MsgBox "Hello"

    Me.InputBeginn = ""
    Me.InputEnd = ""
    
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: `Null` in databases is not the same as an empty string - use the function `IsNull` to check

Comment: Thanks, for the really quick answer!
Answer the question that I  can mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In databases, `Null` means "no value" and this is something different than an empty string.

To check for `Null`, you can use the function `IsNull`. If your value can be either `Null` or an empty string, you can use the `Nz`-function: Nz(anyValue, "") will return an empty string if *anyValue* is null, else it will return *anyValue* itself:

```
If Nz(anyValue, "") = "" Then
```

Note that this is no SQL standard, for Oracle users, its `NVL`, for MS SQL it's `IfNull`)

Comment: `IfNull` is MySql, in MS SQL it's [`IsNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (sic). SQL standard would be `COALESCE`, but that's not valid VBA.

Comment: Sure (cannot test at the moment)? `IsNull` checks for Null and returns True or False, `IfNull` converts Null into a default value.

Comment: Yep. In MS SQL Server (I assume that's what you meant with "MS SQL"), checking for null is done with `expression IS [NOT] NULL` , and the confusingly named `ISNULL(expression, replacementValue)` is similar to VBA's `Nz`. Here's the link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: An annoying thing is that `Nz` is not actually a VBA function, but a method of the Access application object, making it usable as a function when working from Access itself. But not when using DAO/ODBC/OLEDB. Using it in VBA is generally fine (as long as you don't expect code to be portable to say Excel), using it in queries is risky and will cause your query to error in certain contexts. However, you can simply concatenate a zero-length string to replace `NULL` with an empty string: `If anyValue & "" = "" Then`.

Comment: @ErikA Good hint with the `Nz`-function, had forgotten about that. However, I don't like the attempt to concatenate `Null` with anything because while it works in VBA, it will fail on most databases.

Comment: @FunThomas Meh, most databases have both null-propagating and null-ignoring concatenation, e.g. `+` and `CONCAT` in T-SQL, and so does Access. The only difference is that null-ignoring concatenation is often a function, while it is an operator in Access.

Comment: Ask Oracle about that...

Answer (score 0):

In Access, an empty textbox is *Null* even when bound, as you normally should not allow empty strings in the table field. Thus:

```vb
Private Sub Student_AfterUpdate()

    If IsNull(Me!Student.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Hello"

        ' Reset textboxes.
        Me!InputBeginn.Value = Null
        Me!InputEnd.Value = Null
    End If

End Sub
```